# Is a blackish-green tint to a tomato plant still a healthy plant?

Tags: tomatoes, leaves

Does the darker tomato plant look healthy?

There is about an inch of coffee grounds on top of the new potting soil. The taller plant has a darker stem but the smaller one has lighter foliage.

[image: dark tinted tomato plant]

Comment: Are they the same breed?

Comment: Yes, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I have seen this on my tomatoes as well.  For me it seems to be perfectly fine.  Some close up pictures of your plan may help as well.

Comment: wish i could, but i only have a laptop.

Comment: The pot looks too small to me to contain both plants.

Comment: A 5 gallon pot looks too small?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't explain why one tomato plant is darker than the other, but I can tell you that coffee grounds and tomatoes don't go together - tomato plants don't respond well to coffee grounds, plus an inch of coffee grounds round anything isn't a great idea, best to use about half a cup or a small cupful and work into the soil (in the border). See link for further info and confirmation

http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/composting/ingredients/coffee-grounds-gardening.htm

I realise its very fashionable to shovel coffee grounds endlessly round the garden, or any growing thing at the moment, there are wondrous claims for its usefulness all over the web, many of which are either not at all, or not particularly, valid. I'm sure coffee shops must be thrilled that so many people want their waste product, must be saving them bundles of money, but quite honestly, absolutely the best use of grounds is on the compost heap - or small amounts around acid loving shrubs.